# Screaming Frog hreflang missing confirmation links for rel="alternative"

Tags: hreflang, screaming-frog

Screaming frog tells me that I have missing confirmation links in my hreflang, but I cannot seem to identify the problem. Here is a screenshot of the code on our Korean page:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the code on our regular US page. Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two potential problems. The language code is in [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) format while the country/region code is in [ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) format.

*Issue 1 (minor):*

- ISO 639-1 should be written in lowercase `en`
- ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 should be written in uppercase `GB`
- Example: `en-GB`

*Issue 2 (major):*

You seem to be using `rel="alternative" which doesn't exist:

> [SOURCE](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)
>
> Error: Bad value alternative for attribute rel on element link: The
>   string alternative is not a registered keyword.

Change all alternative occurrences to `alternate`. I also recommend that you use a proper markup checker rather than screaming frog, such as W3C validator. By doing it'll help you narrow down problems with more explanation, since its obvious that Screaming Frog failed you in this instance.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I was losing my mind. Beside those two fixes do you see any other issues with the hreflang?

Comment: "The country code is in ISO 639-1 format while the language is in ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 format." - You mean the other way round: "ISO 639-1" defines the language code, whereas "ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2" defines the country/region code. However, whilst the country codes are generally defined as uppercase, these values are _always_ compared case-insensitively. So, any differences in case is purely cosmetic. In fact, many authoritative examples (including [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)) include all lowercase country codes in their `hreflang` attributes.

Comment: @MrWhite, feel free to improve answers by clicking 'edit'.